# How to replace a resttemplate implementation with webclient

Tags: spring, webclient, resttemplate, reactor

I'm trying to replace a resttemplate implementation with a webclient one. The tricky stuff here is that I need to modify a property from an input object, when the response resolves. I don't find the way to achieve it...

This is the resttemplate code:

```
public Instance login(final Instance instancia, final LoginDTO dto) {
        String url = instancia.getBalancer() + API_AUTHENTICATE_PATH;
        HttpEntity<LoginDTO> request = generateRequest(dto);
        ResponseEntity<JWTToken> token = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, JWTToken.class);
        instancia.setToken(token.getBody().getIdToken());
        return instancia;   
}
```

And this is what I have until now:

```
    @Override
    public Mono<Instance> login(Instance instancia, LoginDTO dto) {

        Mono<JWTToken> monoToken=webClient.post().uri(url).body((BodyInserters.fromObject(dto))).retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(JWTToken.class);

        return {....};

    }
```

I'm stucked in that part, because I don't find the way to alter the Instance object...

And there is another point: This is injected in another class, because I need to run this request in parallel against multiple targets. So, a block call is not enough.

Does someone have an idea about how to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If I understood you right than you can do following:
JWTToken jWTToken = monoToken.block();

Comment: Yep, that would be a nice option. Unfortunately I forgot to tell that the use case is calling in parallel from another class and inject this as a client. So... I need to process all the calls in parallel.

In fact, I'm gonna edit the question. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks a lot!

Comment: You have a Mono<JWTToken>, and you want to return a Mono<Instance>. To transform a Mono into another Mono, you use one of the many methods, called operators in the rx jargon, of the Mono class. in this case, the most commonly used one: map(): https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved easily as following:

```
@Override
public Mono<Instance> login(Instance instancia, LoginDTO dto) {
    return webClient
            .post()
            .uri(url)
            .body((BodyInserters.fromObject(dto)))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(JWTToken.class)
            .map(token -> {
                instancia.setToken(token.getBody().getIdToken());
                return instancia;
            });
}
```

Comment: Hi, Stepan! Thanks a lot for your help! I will give it a try!!